# Create Labels from Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, printing

I am nto sure what would eb the best approach for this.

My Scenario:

I am logging my inventory in Excel. I have fields for Serial#, ItemCondition, and sku. I am wanting to print a customer 2' x 3' label with all of this information(the labels come 10 per page, I have a word template)

I know this question may be lacking, but what would be the best way to go about doing this? I have ASp.NET at my disposal if needed.

Comment: A little vba to fill the data in the proper format in a second sheet would be my approach

Comment: If you can organize the data into a table, then MS-Word's [mailmerge](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx) should give you the setup you need

Answer (score 0):

You could change the print area size from the "Page Setup" menu. If paper size options don't match your setup, you can change the margins to fit.

From there, change the height and width of the cells in your spreadsheet to match the word template.